# How to change certain words into the tagged forms of training lists

Tags: r

I tried to change certain strings into the forms of tagged words listed in `train`.

```
train = c('love/POS','happy/POS','sad/NEG','fearsome/NEG','lazy/NEG')
test = c('I love you', 'I am so happy now', 'You look sad somehow', 'the lazy boy look so fearsome')
```

With them, I wanted to make an outcome like

```
[1]'I love/POS you' 'I am so happy/POS now' 'You look sad/NEG somehow' 'the lazy/NEG boy look so fearsome/NEG'
```

Of course, I can use `gsub` like this as a primitive way

```
part1 = gsub('love', 'love/POS', test)
part2 = gsub('happy', 'happy/POS', part1)
.......
```

However, this way is not productive at all when I have bigger training lists.

In order to make it possible in a more effective way, I tried

```
process1 = unlist(strsplit(test, '[[:space:]]+'))

mgsub <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
  if (length(pattern)!=length(replacement)) {
    stop("pattern and replacement do not have the same length.")
  }
  result <- x
  for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
    result <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], result, ...)
  }
  result
}

trainedtest = mgsub(process1, train, test)
trainedtest
```

In fact, it is not working at all because the length of `process1` and `train` lists are not same. Technically, I should make a program which can select certain words to change into tagged forms of train lists, calculating similarities between `process1` and `train`.

Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: If this is mainly an optimization problem, what sizes are we talking about? Or is your goal simply to write a gsub function that does gsub for multiple patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `match` with `nomatch = 0` (i.e. return nothing for no match - default is NA)

```
v1 <- sub('/.*', '', train)
sapply(strsplit(test, ' '), function(i)
       {i[grepl(paste(v1, collapse = '|'), i)] <- train[match(i, v1, nomatch = 0)]; 
                                                              paste(i, collapse = ' ')})

#[1] "I love/POS you"    "I am so happy/POS now"  "You look sad/NEG somehow"             
#[4] "the lazy/NEG boy look so fearsome/NEG"
```

Comment: Thank You So Much! It helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace multiple patterns with desired strings use `gsubfn`:

```
require(gsubfn)
input = c("I love you", "I am so happy now")
toreplace<-list("love" = "love/POS", "happy" = "happy/POS")
gsubfn(paste(names(toreplace),collapse="|"),toreplace, input)
```